# Debugging a practice C++ program with functions Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cin

My C++ textbook asks me to write a program to calculate tax owed. I did so, but when the program executes, I only see the line "Are you married? True/False" and once I enter text, a few more lines are outputted and the program immediately ends. It's supposed to ask the user a few more questions and store the input in variables that are then manipulated, but the program quits before it has the chance to do that. Where are the mistakes? Thank you so much.

```
    // ch7progExercise5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getData(bool& marriedVal, int& childVal, int& salaryVal, double& pensionVal);
double taxAmount(bool marriedVal, int childVal, int salaryVal, double pensionVal);

bool married;
int children, grossSalary;
double pensionPercent;

int main()
{
    getData(married, children, grossSalary, pensionPercent);
    taxAmount(married, children, grossSalary, pensionPercent);
    return 0;
}

void getData(bool& marriedVal, int& childVal, int& salaryVal, double& pensionVal)
{
    cout << "Are you married? True/False" << endl;
    cin >> marriedVal;
    if(marriedVal)
    {
        cout << "How many children under the age of 14 do you have?" << endl;
        cin >> childVal;
    }
    cout << "What is your gross salary? If married, provide combined income." << endl;
    cin >> salaryVal;
    cout << "What percentage of your gorss income did you contribute to a pension fund?" << endl;
    cin >> pensionVal;
}

double taxAmount(bool marriedVal, int childVal, int salaryVal, double pensionVal)
{
    double standardExemption, pension, taxRate, tax, taxableIncome;
    int numPeople, personalExemption;
    if (marriedVal)
    {
        standardExemption = 7000;
        numPeople = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        standardExemption = 4000;
        numPeople = 1;
    }
    numPeople += childVal;
    personalExemption = 1500 * numPeople;
    pension = pensionVal*salaryVal;
    taxableIncome = salaryVal - (standardExemption + pension + personalExemption);
    if (taxableIncome < 15000)
    {
        taxRate = 0.15;
        tax = taxRate*taxableIncome;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome < 40000)
    {
        taxRate = 0.25;
        tax = 2250 + taxRate*(taxableIncome - 15000);
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 40000)
    {
        taxRate = 0.35;
        tax = 8460 + taxRate*(taxableIncome - 40000);
    }
    else
        cout << "Invalid income" << endl;
    cout << tax << endl;
    return tax;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger to find out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx

Comment: By default the streams use 0 and 1 for `bool`. To enable true/false you have to use [`cin >> boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use true, use 1.
when this gets executed `cout << "Are you married? True/False" << endl;`
in the command prompt, make sure that as a response you are putting a 1 instead of true. this will solve your problem.

Comment: No problem, please pick as answer to the question gets closed.

Comment: How do I pick as answer?